# Hiding a link depending on date in PHP

Tags: php, date, if-statement

I am displaying a number of dates using PHP and I need to hide them when a certain date has expired.

I am using an IF statement to run this but it doesn't seem to be working.

Any suggestions would be great

```
<?PHP if('09-19-2016'<DATE('m-d-Y') || $_SESSION['role'] == 'Administrator') echo('<li><a href="?page=itRooms&weekId=2">Week 2 - W/C 12/09/2016</li></a>');?>
```

Comment: Can you explain it more

Comment: So I have a list of dates Week 1 through to week 50, I am aiming to have the if statement hide the date if the date has passed and they are not an administrator. At the moment it is showing all the dates regardless - I know the administrator part of the IF statement is working but the date section isnt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're doing

```
'09-19-2016' < date('m-d-Y')
```

You're ending up comparing two strings, these can't be evaluated as "greater than" or "less than". You'll need to convert it to timestamps or use DateTime objects to do it. Also, the date format isn't correct.

```
<?php 
$date_string = "09/19/2016";

// Using objects 
$current_date = new DateTime();
$your_date    = new DateTime($date_string);
if ($your_date < $current_date || $_SESSION['role'] == 'Administrator') 
    echo'<li><a href="?page=itRooms&weekId=2">Week 2 - W/C 12/09/2016</li></a>';

// Using timestamps
if (strtotime($date_string) < time() || $_SESSION['role'] == 'Administrator') 
    echo'<li><a href="?page=itRooms&weekId=2">Week 2 - W/C 12/09/2016</li></a>';
```

Choose either one of the above - both will work, although I find objects easier to work with.

---

From your comments,

> hide the date if the date has passed

Note that when using the less than operator `<`, doing `$date < $now` will evaluate to true if the date is in the *past*, and hide the content if the date is in the future. If you desire the opposite behavior, you just use the greater than operator `<`.

Here's a live demo: https://3v4l.org/N74G2

## References

- http://php.net/datetime.construct
- http://php.net/strtotime
- http://php.net/language.operators.comparison

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much - I will use the objects it's a lot tidier! Knew it would be something simple like this

Comment: Happy to help! :-) If you found this answer the most helpful, please accept it :-)

Comment: Strings *can* be compared, they just need to be in a more meaningful format in this case. "2016-09-19" can safely be compared with another date in the same format.

Comment: @BobbyJack Yeah, you're right, honestly I wasn't aware  - I've always just used objects or timestamps, TIL! https://3v4l.org/GFaPi

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse your date from your format '09-19-2016' to a timestamp or DateTime object, which PHP will be able to compare as a date. You can use PHP's [date_parse_from_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php) to do so.

For example:

```
$date = '09-19-2017';

$parsed = date_parse_from_format('m-d-Y', $date);
$timestamp = mktime(
    $parsed['hour'],
    $parsed['minute'],
    $parsed['second'],
    $parsed['month'],
    $parsed['day'],
    $parsed['year']
);

if ($timestamp < time()) {
    echo 'older';
} else {
    echo 'newer';
}
```

This will give you the correct answer while keeping your current format. You can see an working example here: https://3v4l.org/NIoId